# Error when reading a control's location from a textfile in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to save and load the location of some of my controls in a text file.
I get the following error:

*Expression is a value and therefore cannot be the target of an assignment.*

**Saving code:**

```
Private Sub save_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles save.Click
        Dim Opslaan As StreamWriter

        Opslaan = New StreamWriter("Y:\Jordy Steyaert\Scania Tool Data\40-zone\locaties.txt", False)

        Opslaan.WriteLine(TextBox1.Name & "|" & TextBox1.Location.X)
        Opslaan.WriteLine(TextBox1.Name & "|" & TextBox1.Location.Y)

        Opslaan.Flush()
        Opslaan.Close()
    End Sub
```

**Loading code:**

```
    Private Sub Laden()
        Dim Laden As StreamReader
        Dim prop(5) As String

        If File.Exists("Y:\Jordy Steyaert\Scania Tool Data\40-zone\locaties.txt") Then
            Laden = New StreamReader("Y:\Jordy Steyaert\Scania Tool Data\40-zone\locaties.txt", False)
            Do Until Laden.EndOfStream
                prop = Laden.ReadLine().Split("|")

                If String.Equals(prop(0), TextBox1.Name) Then
                    TextBox1.Location.X = prop(1) 'Expression is a value and therefore cannot be the target of an assignment.
                End If

                If String.Equals(prop(0), TextBox1.Name) Then
                    TextBox1.Location.Y = prop(1) 'Expression is a value and therefore cannot be the target of an assignment.
                End If

            Loop
            Laden.Close()
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

Is there an easier way of saving and reading a location from a file? I know it's possible using `My.Settings` but I need to be able to ready it from a simple textfile.

Comment: You don't appear to have assigned any values to `prop`. Also, if you use [Option Strict On](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zcd4xwzs.aspx) then it will point out some type inconsistency problems which you should fix.

Comment: `TextBox1.Location = New Point(intX, intY)`  ...and yes, turn on option strict because strings are not numbers.  looks like you are trying to set X and Y to the same value read (`prop(1)`)

Comment: `prop = Laden.ReadLine().Split("|")` - this is not the assignment?

Comment: BTW Settings would save the data as the correct type ie save `.Location` as a `Point` to save lots and lots of code

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I managed to solve my issue. Answer is added

Answer (score 0):

Managed to solve my problem. I assigned both X and Y value to the property's and made them save and read from the same line. I am now able to drag around my controls and save the locations to a text file so when multiple computers are using the program at once they will be able to see the changes.

```
Private Sub save_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles save.Click
    Dim Opslaan As StreamWriter

    Opslaan = New StreamWriter("Y:\Jordy Steyaert\Scania Tool Data\40-zone\locaties.txt", False)

    Opslaan.WriteLine(TextBox1.Name & "|" & TextBox1.Location.X & "|" & TextBox1.Location.Y)

    Opslaan.Flush()
    Opslaan.Close()
End Sub

Private Sub Laden()
    Dim Laden As StreamReader
    Dim prop(2) As String
    Dim intX As Integer
    Dim intY As Integer

    If File.Exists("Y:\Jordy Steyaert\Scania Tool Data\40-zone\locaties.txt") Then
        Laden = New StreamReader("Y:\Jordy Steyaert\Scania Tool Data\40-zone\locaties.txt", False)
        Do Until Laden.EndOfStream
            prop = Laden.ReadLine().Split("|")

            If String.Equals(prop(0), TextBox1.Name) Then
                intX = prop(1)
                intY = prop(2)
            End If

        Loop
        Laden.Close()
    End If

    TextBox1.Location = New Point(intX, intY)
End Sub
```

Comment: If you are going to post answers, they should compile under Option Strict. `intY = prop(2)` wont compile and there are those who will DV such answers